# Chrome automatically brings packaged app window into foreground when selecting it

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

### Description

Chrome packaged app windows are always brought to the foreground when selecting Google Chrome via `CMD-Tab` or by clicking Chromes Dock Icon.
Is there any property or trick that could prevent this behaviour?

[image: Gif of the issue]

### Code

You can reproduce this behaviour with almost [every chrome app](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples).

```
chrome.app.window.create('window.html', {
  id: 'someId',
  focused: true
});
```

Comment: https://crbug.com/new

Comment: Thanks @DanielHerr I filed an issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=623338